# Can I use Eclipse CDT to debug a PIC18 using PICkit3?

Tags: pic

I'm curious and interested in buying a PIC18 micro and a PICkit3 to do some programming on a breadboard, to learn a bit. I like using Eclipse CDT for C development quite a bit.

Is it possible to use Eclipse rather than MPLab X, the Netbeans version?

Comment: Something like this probably wont be impossible, but the difficultly and time involved might be high. Check out the link. It might point you in the right direction or maybe you'll choose a dsPic instead. http://www.yumantech.org/wiki/Technical/Tools/PIC30DevelopmentWithEclipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically, it's possible to build stuff. The XC toolchains are based around GCC, so if you could figure out all of the needed command-line arguments, they should work with any IDE. That being said, one of the nice things about using the IDE is it abstracts those command-line arguments away into nice menus and GUIs.

Where you may run into difficulty is flashing and debugging, as these are functions of the IDE itself (to the best of my understanding) and not the XC toolchains themselves.